# Argument Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty) for Form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, partials

I am trying to make a quiz module in which the answer to each multiple choice question is recorded and traced to the appropriate user.  Since the edit and new views will both use the same form, I'm using a partial.

When I try to view the new view I'm getting an argument error saying "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

The controller is:

```
class QuizBsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in

  def show
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.new
  end

  def create
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.new

    @quiz_bs.bs01 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs01]
    @quiz_bs.bs02 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs02]
    @quiz_bs.bs03 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs03]
    @quiz_bs.bs04 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs04]
    @quiz_bs.bs05 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs05]
    @quiz_bs.bs06 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs06]

    @quiz_bs.user = current_user

    if quiz_bs.save
      flash[:notice] = "Quiz results saved successfully."
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your quiz results failed to save."
      redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
  end

  def update
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:quiz_bs])

    @quiz_bs.assign_attributes(quiz_bs_params)

    if @quiz_bs.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated successfully."
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
  end

  private
  def quiz_bs_params
    params.require(:quiz_bs).permit(:bs01, :bs02, :bs03, :bs04, :bs05, :bs06)
  end

end
```

The new view is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="quiz_bs_new" class="text-center">
    <h1>Body Structure Quiz</h1>
  </div>

<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { quiz: @quiz_bs } %>

</div>
<div class="buffer-50"></div>
```

And here's my form partial:

```
<%= form_for @quiz do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label "Question Text" %><br>
          <div class="radio left-padding-30">
            <%= f.radio_button :bs01, '1'%><label>31 Seconds or More</label><br>
            <%= f.radio_button :bs01, '2'%><label>26 - 30 Seconds</label><br>
            <%= f.radio_button :bs01, '3'%><label>21 - 25 Seconds</label><br>
            <%= f.radio_button :bs01, '4'%><label>16 - 20 Seconds</label><br>
            <%= f.radio_button :bs01, '5'%><label>10 - 15 Seconds</label><br>
            <%= f.radio_button :bs01, '6'%><label>6 - 9 Seconds</label><br>
            <%= f.radio_button :bs01, '7'%><label>0 - 5 Seconds</label>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- column end -->
  </div> <!-- row end -->

    <div class="buffer-25"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 center-block">
        <div class="center-block"><%= f.submit %></div>
      </div> <!-- column end -->
  </div> <!-- row end -->

<% end %>
```

Comment: ist `update` or `new` ? also post your `rake routes`, thats ez fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables get passed to partials as local variables. Use `quiz` instead of `@quiz` in your form partial should fix the issue.

**EDIT**

Also set the url in your form_for to make sure the form routes to the right controller action:

`form_for quiz, url: quiz_bs_path, method: :post`

and replace `quiz_bs_path` with whatever route maps to QuizBsController#create

Comment: That at least changed the error.  Now I'm getting a no method error saying"undefined method `quiz_bs_index_path' "...

Comment: Same one: `<%= form_for quiz do |f| %>`